# Play live stream

Tags: macos, unix, rtmp, vlc

Is there a gui or better yet something via terminal for the Mac (unix) that can play a rtmp live stream? So be able to enter the rtmp address and also the stream name? I have tried VLC with no luck. I'm on Snow Leopard.

I just want to have a window pop open and the stream be available to view...like when you play a file via command line for mPlayer.

Comment: Better suited to superuser.com

Comment: "I have tried VLC with no luck"... try harder :D No, seriously it is the best solution and it should work. (Although you can check out ffmpeg or mplayer, they probably get the job done too).

Answer (score 2):

why not just create some embed code in a html page and point the stream at that?

Download the jw flash player demo and just change the rtmp stream.